# JNI ported libusb-compat can't find devices in application, can outside application

Tags: android, usb, libusb

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII which has USB host support built in, and a Motorola Droid (original) which also has USB host "hacked" in.  The SGSII runs Android 3.x and the Droid runs 2.x.

I ported libusb-compat to Android (mainly just cross-compiling it) so that I can plug in an external device and use it, which has a driven that requires libusb-compat.  The driver was also ported to Android and links to my port of libusb-compat.  On top of all of this is an application which has a JNI interface to use the driver and libusb-compat.

On the Droid running Android 2.x, all of this works perfectly.  I can initialize the device with my ported driver, and it can use libusb-compat to do its thing.

However, on the SGSII running 3.x, calls to libusb-compat to list USB devices, query them, etc. all fail.  Libusb-compat running from within my application is able to find the root USB bus, but the list of USB devices always comes up empty and queries to them fail.

Now, if I compile a simple standalone executable which links to libusb-compat and simply tries to list the USB devices and run it *outside* of my application (e.g., in an adb shell), it is able to find the root bus and all of the USB devices on the SGSII.  This leads me to believe that the sandbox the application runs in on Android 3.x is blocking libusb-compat from accessing the USB devices.  Likely for permission issues on a device which supports USB host.

I tried adding this to my manifest, but it did not help:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

Does anything stand out that I am doing wrong or need to add for libusb-compat to work within my application?  Again, it works if I build a standalone application with the ndk that uses my libusb-compat driver.

Comment: The main issue is that something run from the adb shell has higher linux-level permissions than something run under an application userid.  Since it doesn't seem like your implementation is using the new Android USB APIs, manifest permissions related to those are probably irrelevant and you would have to figure out how to hack the device node permissions.  It would probably be a better long-term solution to port your driver to the android USB host APIs for devices which support that, and keep the linux method only as a root-required hack for older devices.

Comment: interesting point.  It could very well be user permissions, you're right.  I am running the standalone application as root in a shell.  I'm really not looking for anything long term or widely supportable, so I'm going to poke around permissions in the kernel and see if I can bypass them.  Thanks for the pointer.  I'll post if this ended up being the issue.

Comment: Why not use the `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in the manifest and sign it with the rom's key?

Comment: interesting!  I had never heard of this before, but it makes sense.  I have done some digging on it, and I've found how to add that to the manifest, but I can't figure out how to "sign" my application code.  Do you know of any guides on this.  I'm using the standard OS (not a custom ROM), but it is rooted.